# Permutations with replacement and rules in R

Tags: r, iterator, permutation

I need to do a kind of Truth table to use with Monte Carlo Simulations.

Basically I need to generate permutations for 0 and 1 with 110 "Operand", but with some rules.

Ex: It can't have two zeros side by side

An example using 3 columns (I need 110)

```
c_1 c_2  c_3
0    0   0 = DROP
0    0   1 = DROP
0    1   0 = OK
0    1   1 = OK
1    0   0 = DROP
1    0   1 = OK
1    1   0 = OK
1    1   1 = OK
```

I'm trying to use package arrangements, but I have no clue in how apply the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create test data, `g`, and then paste the columns together and use `grep` to find the rows that don't have double zeros.  Then index `g` by that.

```
g <- expand.grid(c_1 = 0:1, c_2 = 0:1, c_3 = 0:1) # test data

ok <- ! grepl("00", do.call("paste0", g))
g[ok, ]
```

giving:

```
  c_1 c_2 c_3
3   0   1   0
4   1   1   0
6   1   0   1
7   0   1   1
8   1   1   1
```

### One row

If you have a single row as a vector then use `as.list` on it to use the above:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 1)
! grepl("00", do.call("paste0", as.list(x)))
## [1] TRUE
```

### Enumeration

If there are n columns there cannot be more than ceiling(n/2) zeros in any row so to enumerate all possibilities we can enumerate all rows with one zero, then two zeros, ..., ceiling(n/2) zeros.  Using arrangements package for k zeros NotDoubleZero initializes a structure and iter iterates it until there are no more at which point it returns NULL

```
library(arrangements)

NotDoubleZero <- function(n, k = 0) {
  structure(NA, icomb = icombinations(n, k))
}

iter <- function(x, ...)  {
  if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  icomb <- attr(x, "icomb")
  n <- icomb$n
  k <- icomb$k
  repeat {
    r <- icomb$getnext()
    if (is.null(r) || all(diff(r) > 1)) break
  }
  if (is.null(r)) {
    k <- k + 1
    if (k > ceiling(n/2)) return(NULL)
    x <- NotDoubleZero(n, k)
    iter(x)
  } else structure(r, icomb = icomb)
}

# test
res <- NotDoubleZero(3)
while(!is.null(res <- iter(res))) cat("Positions of 0's: <", res, "> \n")
```

giving:

```
Positions of 0's: <  >   <- no zeros, i.e. all ones
Positions of 0's: < 1 > 
Positions of 0's: < 2 > 
Positions of 0's: < 3 > 
Positions of 0's: < 1 3 >
```

### Random row given k

This gives the positions of the zeros in a random row given n (the number of columns) and k (the number of zeros).  You could generate k randomly too but that won't give a uniform distribution over rows; however, maybe this is sufficient anyways.

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 3
k <- 2
repeat {
  r <- sort(sample(n, k))
  if (all(diff(r) > 1)) break
}
r
## [1] 1 3

1 - replace(numeric(n), r, 1)
## [1] 0 1 0
```

Comment: The main problem is with 110 columns I can't store data in memory. It needs to be iterated.

Comment: I think it should work, The problem is the number of rows. 2^110 = 1.298e33

Comment: Have added sections on enumeration and generating random rows; however, the last one requires the number of zeros as an input.